# converting to datetime time and extracting month name

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a date in the format '201501', I imported the table from excel so it is not in datetime datatype, I want to extract/return the month name. How can convert this '201501' into datetime while also getting month name.

Comment: So what is that date? `YYYYMM` ?

Comment: What should the day value be for your datetime values?

Comment: What data type can i use for just YearMonth @BerndLinde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YYYYMMDD` is safe so you can:

```
;with t(example) as 
(
    select '201512'
)
select
    cast(example + '01' as date) as [DATE],
    datename(month, cast(example + '01' as date)) as [MONTH]
from t


DATE        MONTH
2015-12-01  December
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(substring("201501",5,6),"%m"),"%M") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you default your day to the first of each month.

```
declare @dt varchar(10)
declare @year datetime

set @dt = '201501'
Set @year = convert(datetime,Substring(@dt, 1,4) + '-' + Substring(@dt, 5,2) + '-01')


select @year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month ,CAST( substring('201501',5,2) AS int),-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
declare @mydate as varchar(8);
set @mydate = '201501';

SELECT
   DATENAME(MONTH,
   CAST(
      convert(VARCHAR(8), @mydate + CAST('01' AS VARCHAR(2)), 112)
   AS DATETIME))
```

Output: `January`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert this in to Datetime. 
One option I suggest is to split that in to year and month then create it in any date format by adding 01 as the date ex: if the format is YYYY/MM/DD then 2015/01/01 
and finaly use this 
select datename(month, '2015/01/01')